# spring boot start up error

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I get the below error when i start up spring boot. 
The application is able to start up fine even if this error is reported in the logs.

Has anybody faced this issue ? Will this impact the hibernate operations during run time ?

```
2017-06-14 10:04:26.186  INFO 8376 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityM
anagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence
unit 'default'
2017-06-14 10:04:26.246  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.interna
l.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2017-06-14 10:04:27.562  INFO 8376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version
                  : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.2.Final}
2017-06-14 10:04:27.566  INFO 8376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Envir
onment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-14 10:04:27.569  INFO 8376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Envir
onment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-14 10:04:27.763  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations
.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-14 10:04:27.828  WARN 8376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.url
                  : HHH10000002: File or directory named by URL [file:/D:/MRO/QA
MS/sourcecode/10_04_2017/mro/distribution/qams/microservices/qam-rsk-prediction/
build/libs/my-jar-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] could not be found.  URL will be
ignored

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myproject\build\libs\my-jar-1.0.0.jar!\BOOT-INF\cl
asses (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.res
olveJarFileReference(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.
2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.vis
itArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.ja
r!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.visi
tArchive(JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar!
/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(Abstract
ScannerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordin
ateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Fi
nal]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(
MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98) [hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init
>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:226) [hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.
2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init
>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:161) [hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.
2.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvi
der.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.ja
va:54) [spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.cr
eateNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNat
iveEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-4
.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPro
pertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) [spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.
jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-
beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-bea
ns-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-
4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.
3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEA
SE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEAS
E.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: It isn't an error it is a warning logged from hibernate.

Comment: Looks like path `file:/D:/MRO/QA
MS/sourcecode/10_04_2017/mro/distribution/qams/microservices/qam-rsk-prediction/
build/libs/my-jar-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes` is incorrect. As said by Deinum, it's a warning not an error

Comment: is there a way to fix this warning?